Why is the build-in function that call mail() is undefined function

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mail() in /storage/ssd5/144/22289144/public_html/top_teamPHP/test.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd5/144/22289144/public_html/top_teamPHP/test.php on line 10

Although I checked that the version of my PHP is the same version as the website version
<?php

    $to      = "toemail";
    $title   = "hi";
    $body    = "hello";
    $header  = "from: support@topteam2025.000webhostapp.com". "\n" ."cc: fromemail";  

    if(mail($to, $title, $body, $header)) {
        $myobj = array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'check you email');
        echo json_encode($myobj);
    } else {
        $myobj = array('status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'something went wrong');
        echo json_encode($myobj);
    }
?>


PHP relies on sendmail, so if that wasn't available on whatever OS you're using when  you installed PHP, the mail function won't get compiled in. So: check to see if /usr/sbin/sendmail exists, and if not, you'll want to address that first, then reinstall/recompile PHP

The mail functions are only available when the sendmail binary (or a wrapper of it) is available during compilation. See the Mail: Requirements help page:

For the Mail functions to be available, PHP must have access to the sendmail binary on your system during compile time. If you use another mail program, such as qmail or postfix, be sure to use the appropriate sendmail wrappers that come with them.

